# CSS - All vertical aligning methods not working and some other problems

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a verticaly center some div's. But it is not working.

I am literally working on this for more then 6 hours straight now and I just dont know how I could do this.

This is what I am trying to create:

[image]

"Hallo.jpg"(red arrow) Has to be verticaly centered. **This is my bigest problem. Whatever I try does not work**

"error"(blue arrow) Has to be on the bottom.

The pencil has to be in a fixed position on the same line as "Hallo.jpg" (260px  from "Hallo.jpg")

**HTML + CSS:** (there is some inline styling because it's easier in development when changing elements alot)

```css
#upload-InnerPanel{
        min-height: 300px;
        border: #2196F3 2px dashed;
    }

    .upload-ItemPanel{
        float: left; 
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        max-height: 150px;
        box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px #9E9E9E;
    }

    .upload-ImagePreview{
        width: 150px;
        max-height: 130px;
        object-fit: contain;
    }

    .upload-name{
        max-width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .upload-extension{
        width: 50px;
    }

    .upload-iconButton{
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: red; /* normaly transparent but red for demo */
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .upload-editNameOpen{
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64)
        //Not going to place the whole base64 string here.
    }
```

```html
<div id="upload-InnerPanel">
        <div class="upload-ItemPanel">
            <img class='upload-ImagePreview' src='https://unsplash.it/300/300' style="float: left">
            <div style="float: right">X</div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 260px;">
                <span class="upload-name" id="imageName15">Hallo</span>
                <span class='upload-extension'>.jpg</span>
                <button class="upload-iconButton upload-editNameOpen" id="imageEdit15" title="Edit FileName"></button>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 200px)">error</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would definitely use flex layout instead of float and reduce the code by 2/3. Unless IE9 must be supported...

Comment: You'd be doing yourself a huge favor if you try flexbox instead of floats. There are questions about browser support, but it's much more available than `object-fit`, which is only supported in the latest version of Edge and not any version of IE, so that doesn't seem to be an issue. ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

Comment: Well, I tried a flex layout but did not seem to get it to work. I actually started with flexbox because I know it's better but I just did not get it to work. With flexbox the image streched to it's full 150px setting the image in the middel. and leaving big gaps on the bottom and top. I want the outer div to stretch to the content but I did not got it to work.

Comment: you want the `error` below the image? and can the image name and extension be in the same html element?

Comment: The error message has to be on the bottom on the side of the image and the image name and extension can not be in the same element

Comment: is this the expected output? [output link](https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZHxhlLA82sc)

Comment: Hallo.jpg has to be vertically centered and next to the image.

Comment: is this fine? [expected output](https://imagebin.ca/v/3ZMBzdhsM7uY)

Comment: Yes, it is. But already got an answer from @Alohci what works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get rid of all the `float:left`s and use `display:inline-block` with vertical alignments. Mostly `vertical-align:middle`, with `vertical-align:bottom` for the error. Like this:

```css
.close { float:right; }
.upload-ImagePreview { 
    display:inline; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 150px;
    max-height: 130px;
 }
.desc { 
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:260px; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-right:-264px;
 }
.error { display:inline; vertical-align:bottom; }
.upload-name { 
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.upload-extension { width: 50px; vertical-align:middle; }
.upload-iconButton {
    float:right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red; /* normally transparent but red for demo */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#upload-InnerPanel{
    min-height: 300px;
    border: #2196F3 2px dashed;
}
.upload-ItemPanel{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    max-height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px #9E9E9E;
}
```

```html
<div id="upload-InnerPanel">
  <div class="upload-ItemPanel">
    <img class='upload-ImagePreview' src='https://unsplash.it/300/300' alt="hallo">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <div class="desc">
      <button class="upload-iconButton upload-editNameOpen" id="imageEdit15" title="Edit FileName"></button>
      <span class="upload-name" id="imageName15">Hallo</span>
      <span class='upload-extension'>.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="error">error</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rules are fine, in particular `vertical-align: middle;` is the one that make your image to be centered, the problem is in this line:

```
<img class='upload-ImagePreview' src='https://unsplash.it/300/300' style="float: left">
```

If you remove the `float: left` your image will be center.

```css
#upload-InnerPanel{
        min-height: 300px;
        border: #2196F3 2px dashed;
    }

    .upload-ItemPanel{
        float: left; 
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        max-height: 150px;
        box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px #9E9E9E;
    }

    .upload-ImagePreview{
        width: 150px;
        max-height: 130px;
        object-fit: contain;
    }

    .upload-name{
        max-width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .upload-extension{
        width: 50px;
    }

    .upload-iconButton{
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: red; /* normaly transparent but red for demo */
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .upload-editNameOpen{
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64)
        //Not going to place the whole base64 string here.
    }
```

```html
<div id="upload-InnerPanel">
        <div class="upload-ItemPanel">
            <img class='upload-ImagePreview' src='https://unsplash.it/300/300'>
            <div style="float: right">X</div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 260px;">
                <span class="upload-name" id="imageName15">Hallo</span>
                <span class='upload-extension'>.jpg</span>
                <button class="upload-iconButton upload-editNameOpen" id="imageEdit15" title="Edit FileName"></button>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 200px)">error</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```